# Chrome Browser Cache for multiple sessions

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, session, caching

For automation testing of webpage,
I open 5 selenium automated chrome-browser sessions on same machines(windows), 
Given the max cache size is: 
     Max size: 335544320

Here do they all 5 share this cache size or they individually have 5 separate cache of Max size each.

Because my automation gets stuck with certain screen of my webpage which is a dynamic heavy loaded one,  when multiple sessions are launched.

Comment: Are you seeing any error? What does the error says? Can you provide full stack trace?

Comment: are you using one windows machine with 5 driver instances? What are the characteristics of this machine? (cpu power, RAM, free storage space)

Comment: @JosePita Yes, with single windows machine, 5 driver instances are created for 5 chrome browser sessions. And this sessions get stuck when a navigated to a heavy dynamic page of 500mb while checkign angular stability.

Comment: So here yes, they are sharing same single cache and hence when triggering  5  browser sessions the webpage gets stuck whereas with 1 or 2 sessions on same machine, it doesn't!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It seems I have random files stuck in the cache too.